# How to start and stop an "Automatic" process

Tags: windows, service, batch-file

I have an "automatic" mode process say "BPSAuto".
I need to keep thi process shut for certain time and later restart it.

I used bat file and sheduled the task to stop and start.

I used -->net start BPSAuto --- To start

And --> net stop BPSAuto  --- To stop.

Now my problem is once I stop the process it again starts automatically. May be this is because it is in "Automatic" mode. Plesae help me to stop completely. And later restart.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc config ServiceName start= <setting string>`

note the space between start= and the setting for the service

Setting string can be one of:

- boot
- system
- auto
- demand
- disabled

from `sc config /?`:

```
Modifies a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
SYNTAX:
sc  config [service name]  ...
CONFIG OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec|adapt>
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled>
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```